# Any equivalent of "extended" for C#?

Tags: c#, performance, double, floating-point-precision

I'm working on a new version of my [Mandelbrot screensaver](http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/nicheMANDELBROTsaver) and I'm running out of floating point accuracy - simple [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) values don't have enough significant figures for my needs.

More significant figures = greater levels of zooming into the fractal

Back when I wrote a version of this screensaver in Delphi 7, I used the [extended](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats#The_Extended_type) floating point type, 80 bits in size.

In .NET, I could switch to [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx), but the performance hit for this is terrible, slowing down fractal generation by a factor of 20 or so.

Is there any equivalent of **extended** for .NET? Or, alternatively, are there any numeric types with higher precision than **double** that still use the FPU for evaluation and therefore don't have the high performance hit of **decimal**?

**Update**

My screensaver already manages to zoom into the fractal by many (many!) orders of magnitude; currently it resets to the base fractal only when the numeric type in use is unable to separate the ordinates for adjacent pixels. The extra 16 bits of precision from the double-extended improvement would give me close to 16 more doublings of size.

As to performance, my algorithm already manages to eliminate 95-99% of the math required (as compared to a naive implementation that calculates many pixels), while retaining the integrity of the fractal.

Comment: You probably need to write native code for this, since the extended makes use of the 80-bit floating point register in x86. Or I'm not sure if it is possible to reduce the program's hunger for more precision. I'm not expert on this, so I cannot give any further advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On 64-bit platforms, the `Extended` type is an alias for Double, which
>   is only 8 bytes. On 32-bit platforms, an `Extended` number is represented as 10 bytes (80 bits).

That means even your Delphi program may not perform well in 64bit platforms.

If you need a numeric data type with more than 64bits then go for `decimal` and optimize your algorithms to improve performance.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think you need more absolute precision to compute high-resolution Mandlebrot renders (proven by the fact there are many programs that go near-infinitely deep in very quck speeds). I think the OP just needs to think about solving the problem differently.