# Convert from double to string without rounding in C#

Tags: c#

We have encountered an issue which is the double value is rounded after using .toString() method, in order to show in TextBox.

What we need is something like this:

> Double value: 39621443.8975101998
>
> String Value: 39621443.8975101998

But what we get is:

> Double value: 39621443.8975101998
>
> String Value: 39621443.8975102

We Have Googled it and tried many methodes, but none of then have worked

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: It will be rounded eventually, otherwise it is a number with potentially infinite number of digits. The question is how many digits do you want?

Comment: Actually the number of digits is not predictable, it varies from 1 to 10 or sometimes more digits

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Start having a look here, you may want to simply have to resort to fixed point precision.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: We have tried Fixed-Point so far, but as msdn says it results in Rounded value : 1234.567 ("F", en-US) -> 1234.57. But we need the exact value without any rounding. We have even tried ("R") format specifier, but again we didn't get the desired result

Comment: Double have limited precision. It just can not represent as many digits, as you want. `39621443.897510198==39621443.897510204` this condition as actually true.

Comment: Are you using `ToString()` or `ToString("R")` ? Show code please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any equivalent of "extended" for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549000/any-equivalent-of-extended-for-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want exact value with that many decimals you should use the [`Decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)  data type which has higher precision then `double`. Use `decimal.Parse(str)`.

Answer (score 1):

As @PetSerAl points out, the two values (as represented as an [IEEE 754 double precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision)) are the same.

```
39621443.8975101998 => 0x4182E49A1F2E19D4

39621443.8975102 => 0x4182E49A1F2E19D4

39621443.897510199800000123456789 => 0x4182E49A1F2E19D4
```

Source: [BinaryConvert.net](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html).

RoundTrip won't help you here - this is the *limit* of double precision.

You will need another data type, like @magnus suggests.